# Bootstrap Sidebar not showing on the top

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using this [bootsrtap template](http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/simple-sidebar/) on my web, but the side bar is not starting from start, infect it is showing some distance down, however the content are is perfect.

[image]

```
<div class="container-fluid" style="margin-top:80px; min-height:500px; background-color:orange;">
    <div class="row">

    <div id="wrapper">

        <!-- Sidebar -->
        <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
            <ul class="sidebar-nav">
                <li class="sidebar-brand">
                    <a href="#">
                        Admin Panel
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="email_master_list/">Email Master List</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Shortcuts</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Overview</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Events</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">About</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Services</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /#sidebar-wrapper -->

        <!-- Page Content -->
        <div id="page-content-wrapper" style="background-color:green;">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        {% block contentarea %}
                        <h1>Simple Sidebar</h1>
                        <p>This template has a responsive menu toggling system. The menu will appear collapsed on smaller screens, and will appear non-collapsed on larger screens. When toggled using the button below, the menu will appear/disappear. On small screens, the page content will be pushed off canvas.</p>
                        <p>Make sure to keep all page content within the <code>#page-content-wrapper</code>.</p>
                        <a href="#menu-toggle" class="btn btn-default" id="menu-toggle">Toggle Menu</a>
                        {% endblock %}
                    </div>
                </div>
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
    });
    </script>
</div>         </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /#page-content-wrapper -->

    </div>
    <!-- /#wrapper -->
</script>
</div>
    </div>
     <script>
    $("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
    });
    </script>
</div>
```

I want the black side bar to starts from the top, however on mobile screen it is showing from the top.

Comment: Where's the opening script tag for e.preventDefault();
        $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");

Answer (score 0):

You can position #sidebar-wrapper on top

```
#sidebar-wrapper{
    top:0px;
}
```

Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/bronni/caprkok4/2/

Comment: worked but on the top heading admin panel goes very up. now the side bar starts from email list menu.

Answer (score 0):

U have given ur container itself a margin-top:80px so obviously your sidebar will start from down , though in computed it will show margin-top:0, but if you check the container it has a margin-top:80px;

Comment: that's the margin for outer container, the side bar is inside the container

Comment: I get that but what happens when u remove margin-top:80px of outer container

Comment: no effect, look at @Christoph solution, but it moves too much top so that the top menu admin panel is hides/does not showing.

Comment: check in your computed why it is taking so much margin and if aligning too much on top coz it is top:0px to bring it down add top:10px and accordingly